# Getting location information from GCM registration id

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the GCM push notification mobile service for my application. However currently when i push the notifications, it is pushed to all the devices. However i need to push the notification based on the timings in that countries. e.g. 9 AM for each country. Is there any simple way to implement it? Is it possible to get the location related information from the GCM registration id? I feel that GCM server does maintain the information specific to the country. Please correct if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get location information from the registration ID. What you could do is send location information from your application to your server along with the registration ID. This way, each registration ID will be associated with a location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eran. I am currently in progress of implementing the same solution. However wanted to check if there is any alternate method. Also want to check if its legal to store Location Information of the user in appengine?

Comment: @RajanPhatak I don't know much about appengine, so I can't help you there, but if your only need for the location info is to know when to send the notifications to each device, you don't need to store location. You just need to store the hour of delivery in your local timezone (or the timezone).

Comment: This is regarding Google Push Notification which will be pushed via WebServer. I didn't get how to "store the hour or delivery in local timezone". Can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: @RajanPhatak Well, when you send the registration id to your server, send with it the local time of the device. That would let the server know the time difference between the device's time and the server's time.